# A formula for $S$-units in quaternion algebras

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, quaternions, division-algebras

Let $D=\left(\frac{a,b}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$ be a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Suppose $D$ is ramified at a finite set $S$ of places and $\infty\in S$.
It is known that the $S$-units (the unit group $R_S^1$ of a maximal $\mathcal{O}_S$-order $R_S$) is finite (see [Voight's Quaterinon Algebras](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-56694-4) Proposition 32.3.7 on page 595).

Is there any formula for the cardinality of $R_S^1$? Or any covolume formula for $R_S^1$ in $D_S^1$ where $D_S=\Pi_{p\in S}D\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}_p$? As an analog of [Prasad, G. (1990). Semi-simple groups and arithmetic subgroups](http://repository.ias.ac.in/93841/1/3-p.pdf) .

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/461618/6518